# Fetch json API data from GDAX

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the BTC-EUR ticker from GDAX site to Google Spreadsheet using a script. I got this code but it doesn't work, always returning me error: The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid.

```
  var baseUrl = 'https://api.gdax.com';
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GDAX");

function ticker() {

  var request = "/products/btc-eur/ticker";
  var requestUrl = baseUrl + request;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestUrl);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  var rows = [],
     jsondata;

  for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    jsondata = json[i];
    rows.push([jsondata.price]); 

  }

  dataRange = data.getRange(14, 1, rows.length, 1);
  dataRange.setValues(rows);

}
```

I'm using the same code to push my balance to the spreadsheet, and it is working. I cannot understand why this one return me the error. If I log the json var I get the correct values from the site.
Anyone can help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a following modification?

### Modification points :

The JSON data from `https://api.gdax.com/products/btc-eur/ticker` is as follows. In this data, the value of `price` is only one. So when the JSON data is always like this, you can directly retrieve the value using `json.price`.

```
{
  "trade_id": 4314549,
  "price": "3691.06000000",
  "size": "0.00004053",
  "bid": "3691",
  "ask": "3691.05",
  "volume": "945.78845044",
  "time": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z"
}
```

When this is reflected to your script, the modified script is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function ticker() {
  var baseUrl = 'https://api.gdax.com';
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GDAX");
  var request = "/products/btc-eur/ticker";
  var requestUrl = baseUrl + request;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestUrl);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var rows = [[json.price]];
  var dataRange = data.getRange(14, 1, 1, 1);
  dataRange.setValue(rows);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot! But what if I would like to retrieve more data from that kind of json response?

Comment: @AlxMrx Welcome. Thank you, too. If the data is an array included JSON, you can retrieve the data you want to use for loop like your script. But, in general, the response depends on the request to the API. If you want to retrieve more data, please confirm the API's document.